# How can I get Siri to shuffle all songs by Phish?

Tags: siri

Every time I ask Siri to "shuffle all songs by artist Phish" it shuffles all songs by "Real Big Fish" from my collection instead.

Siri seems unable to understand that "fish" and "phish" are phonetically-equivalent.

Putting aside my suspicions that Siri is secretly judging my tastes in music, how can I get Siri to play the correct artist in this specific case?

Comment: tried pronouncing it p-hish, no 'f' sound? Sometimes, Siri's not as bright as you think ;) It can't pronounce my partner's name either, no matter what I throw at it, though it groks if I use just her first name

Comment: @Tetsujin no dice. I've tried "p hish", "hish", "puh hish" -- all have amusing results, none of which are Phish. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put all your Phish in a playlist, and give it a name like 'tunesofish'. Then simply say "shuffle playlist tunesofish". Siri will open the playlist and play it shuffled.

Here, I've asked Siri to play my Comedy playlist:

[image]

This works with a smart playlist set to auto-add everything from artist "Phish":

[image: Smart playlist settings]

Comment: Requires forethought, but for sure will work. Would also differentiate from the guy who used to sing with Marillion ;)

Comment: If I used a smart playlist to auto-add new content (I have a _lot_ of Phish concerts, more all the time) this might be the best path forward. Edit: smart playlist FTW!

Answer (score 1):

"Hey Siri, shuffle all songs by P H I S H".

Siri will usually let you spell things out, and it works great here.

Comment: No dice. It shuffles songs by "Phi" when I spell it out.

Comment: Hmmm, it worked for me! Maybe spell it faster?

Comment: There is a Happy Hardcore producer named "S3RL" and I was never able to speak his name to Siri even by mimicking the way she pronounces his name, tried it by spelling out the letters (and number :P) and it worked! Thanks Alan, this was helpful.